# Force, Mass, Motion? $E = mc^2$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, forces, mass, mass-energy

Does any object needs force to move? If 'yes', does the matter needs mass to form a force? 
These questions arises from me because $E = mc^2$ and $F = ma$ does not relate and one does not agrees with other.

Comment: The two don't "relate" because the first equation is incomplete and because it has very little to do with the other. I would suggest that you try to understand Newtonian mechanics, first, before you try your hand on relativity. Mixing the two is not a success recipe.

Comment: Please see [our guide](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) on writing good titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does any object needs force to move?

For an object to have a velocity , dx/dt , no force is required, by [Newtons fist law:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_laws_of_motion)

> If 'yes', does the matter needs mass to form a force?

As the answer to the first part is no, the answer to the second one is no, too. It can just have momentum, since mathematically [force is defined as dp/dt.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force#Second_law)

Now in newtonian classical physics everything is supposed to have a mass, and since p=mv , in newtonian physics the answer would be yes.

except that nature has surprises, and it is actually [special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity) mathematics that describes it , which at the limit of low velocities approaches newtonian mechanics. In the [relativistic framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation#Units_of_energy.2C_mass_and_momentum)

[image: relenerg]

there exists energy and momentum , even with mass 0.

> These questions arises from me because E=mc2 and F=ma does not relate and one does not agrees with other.

E=mc^2 is a description of the total energy of a system in relativistic mechanics.

F=ma   is force , not energy, in newtonian mechanics.

F=dp/dt holds for both relativistic and newtonian, but still the connection of force to energy depends on individual conditions of a problem.